# What are the popular, contemporary uses for Perl?

Tags: perl, popularity

What are the popular, contemporary uses for Perl?

**Edit**

I should have been more specific.  I was wondering more on the large scale (popular) what people are using Perl for rather than what it *could* be used for on the individual level.

Comment: this should probably be community wiki

Answer (score 14):

As a glue language, system administrators' language, and now, it is back to taking-over-the-internet using [Catalyst](http://catalystframework.org).

Comment: woot, catalyst, that looks great!

Comment: That's because it is great! ;)

Answer (score 13):

At my University Perl is widely used for Bioinformatic tasks. Automatic changing the format of a Proteindata file, checking with a database transforming the results back and so on. 
So its mostly changing file formats, regular expressions, and parsing of huge datasets

Answer (score 10):

The same as ever: Making the impossible, possible. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Along with Python, the system administrators in my company love it for driving automation tasks.  "If something is worth doing, it's worth automating" seems to be a mantra, and if they can do it in five lines, all the better.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with this question, is that Perl is a very versatile language.  Between code golf and it's similarity to awk/sed, it is still widely used as a glue language and quick go-to language for sysadmin tasks.

With [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/), lots of very useful and more advanced things can be written quickly.

It interfaces well with databases and there are tons of frameworks for web design.  It works quite well with Ajax, as I've noticed through my own use of it.

Get into best practices, and you've got a system that is quite good at doing very large programming tasks.  Heck, the whole of cpan is a testament to Perl's reusability and encapsulation.

See skills that are being sought by employers at http://jobs.perl.org/.

Answer (score 7):

Somewhat confused by the question. For coding.

I think it would be better framed as: What isn't Perl used for? Which I'd answer with: Writing device drivers, anyone got any more?

It's used for gui apps (See Padre), Internet apps (Catalyst), other networking/sockets (POE), accessing databases (DBI), Cryptology (Crypt namespace), Web services (SOAP), Handling binary formats (pack/unpack)...

And of course all manner of text processing.

And that's just the stuff I've used it for.. recently.

Answer (score 6):

Amazon and IMDB uses Perl, more specifically Mason, IIANM.

Answer (score 5):

I currently am using Perl to write an automated testing suite for my company's web sites (using [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) and [`WWW::Selenium`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-WWW-Selenium/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm)).  One of my co-workers is doing the same for other types of servers.  We also use it for our monitoring software ([Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)).  And I use `perl` daily as a commandline tool to aid in basic sysadminy tasks.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a short, simple script to parse some data out of a log file recently.  I find it pretty easy and useful for quick scripting tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Try running this with the terminal size set to at least 120x50 and you will be enlightened ;).

```
                                                   #
                                               sub j(\$){($
                 P,$V)=                      @_;while($$P=~s:^
             ([()])::x){                    $V+=('('eq$1)?-32:31
       }$V+=ord(  substr(                 $$P,0,1,""))-74} sub a{
      my($I,$K,$  J,$L)=@_               ;$I=int($I*$M/$Z);$K=int(
     $K*$M/$Z);$J=int($J*$M             /$Z);$L=int($L*$M/$Z); $G=$
     J-$I;$F=$L-$K;$E=(abs($          G)>=abs($F))?$G:$F;($E<0) and($
      I,$K)=($J,$L);$E||=.01       ;for($i=0;$i<=abs$E;$i++ ){ $D->{$K
              +int($i*$F/$E)      }->{$I+int($i*$G/$E)}=1}}sub p{$D={};$
             Z=$z||.01;map{    $H=$_;$I=$N=j$H;$K=$O=j$H;while($H){$q=ord
            substr($H,0,1,"" );if(42==$q){$J=j$H;$L=j$H}else{$q-=43;$L =$q
          %9;$J=($q-$L)/9;$L=$q-9*$J-4;$J-=4}$J+=$I;$L+=$K;a($I,$K,$J,$ L);
          ($I,$K)=($J,$L)}a($I,$K,$N,$O)}@_;my$T;map{$y=$_;map{ $T.=$D->{$y}
          ->{$_}?$\:' '}(-59..59);$T.="\n"}(-23..23);print"\e[H$T"}$w= eval{
          require Win32::Console::ANSI};$b=$w?'1;7;':"";($j,$u,$s,$t,$a,$n,$o
          ,$h,$c,$k,$p,$e,$r,$l,$C)=split/}/,'Tw*JSK8IAg*PJ[*J@wR}*JR]*QJ[*J'.
           'BA*JQK8I*JC}KUz]BAIJT]*QJ[R?-R[e]\RI'.'}Tn*JQ]wRAI*JDnR8QAU}wT8KT'.
           ']n*JEI*EJR*QJ]*JR*DJ@IQ[}*JSe*JD[n]*JPe*'.'JBI/KI}T8@?PcdnfgVCBRcP'.
            '?ABKV]]}*JWe*JD[n]*JPe*JC?8B*JE};Vq*OJQ/IP['.'wQ}*JWeOe{n*EERk8;'.
              'J*JC}/U*OJd[OI@*BJ*JXn*J>w]U}CWq*OJc8KJ?O[e]U/T*QJP?}*JSe*JCnTe'.
               'QIAKJR}*JV]wRAI*J?}T]*RJcJI[\]3;U]Uq*PM[wV]W]WCT*DM*SJ'.  'ZP[Z'.
                  'PZa[\]UKVgogK9K*QJ[\]n[RI@*EH@IddR[Q[]T]T]T3o[dk*JE'.  '[Z\U'.
                    '{T]*JPKTKK]*OJ[QIO[PIQIO[[gUKU\k*JE+J+J5R5AI*EJ00'.  'BCB*'.
                         'DMKKJIR[Q+*EJ0*EK';sub h{$\ = qw(% & @ x)[int    rand
                          4];map{printf  "\e[$b;%dm",int(rand 6)+101-60*   ($w
                           ||0);system(  "cls")if$w ;($A,$S)=    ($_[1],   $
                            _[0]);($M,   @,)= split  '}';for(     $z=256
                            ;$z>0; $z   -=$S){$S*=   $A;p @,}      sleep$_
                            [2];while   ($_[3]&&($    z+=$ S)       <=256){
                            p@,}}("".   "32}7D$j"     ."}AG".       "$u}OG"
                            ."$s}WG"    ."$t",""      ."24}("        ."IJ$a"
                            ."}1G$n"    ."}CO$o"     ."}GG$t"        ."}QC"
                             ."$h}"      ."^G$e"    ."})IG"          ."$r",
                             "32}?"       ."H$p}FG$e}QG$r".          "}ZC"
                             ."$l",          "28}(LC" .""            ."".
                             "$h}:"           ."J$a}EG".             "$c"
                             ."}M"             ."C$k}ZG".            "$e"
                             ."}"             ."dG$r","18"          ."}("
                            ."D;"            ."$C"  )}{h(16         ,1,1,0
                           );h(8,          .98,0,0   );h(16         ,1,1,1)
                           ;h(8.0         ,0.98,0,     1);         redo}###
                         #written                                 060204 by
                       #liverpole                                  @@@@@@@
                    #@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Comment: This is an all-time use scenario for Perl -- geek art :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can find out quite a bit about what people are currently doing with Perl by taking a look at the posts submitted to the [Enlightened Perl Iron Man Challenge](http://ironman.enlightenedperl.org/).

Personally, I'm currently using it to build the site for (yet another) AJAX-enabled, Twitterfied, etc., etc. social networking startup.

Answer (score 4):

Web sites, data processing/extraction, system administration, task automation, even GUI programming. Mathematics, bioinformatics, chemistry, geology programs.

Answer (score 2):

At my company we used to use Perl to run hundreds of RegEx's to transform random publisher files into SGML to make electronic books.  Alas, those days are over now that we've updated our systems to XML books.

Answer (score 0):

I use Perl for what it has been designed: a **P**ractical way for **E**xtracting useful information from raw data and presenting them in human-readable **R**eports. This is a very nice **L**anguage for this task.